# Short story - human mating season created, backfires on creators

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, sexuality

I'm looking for a short story that I probably read in an anthology in the 1980s- I suspect the story is from.the 1950s or earlier (In my memory I associate it with [Hyperpilosity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperpilosity)).

In this story a man wishes to  reduce the power of women (it's a rather sexist story) by altering humanity so people have a brief, periodic mating season rather than being interested in sex at all times. He and his friends  arrange this (somehow) - but we learn that his wife was well aware of his plans and let them be accomplished, because the mating season gives her more power and less trouble (most of the time he doesn't want sex, but he's always nice to her so that when he **really** wants it, she's agreeable).  I have a vague memory that the story ends with the wife and her friends comparing gifts they've received from their husbands recently.

It's not Brin's Glory Season, though there are some similarities.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

["Never Underestimate"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68330), a short story by [Theodore Sturgeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Sturgeon), first published in [*If*, March 1952](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58777+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/1952-03_IF/page/n99/mode/2up). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?68330), perhaps the [Groff Conklin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groff_Conklin) anthology [*Omnibus of Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?130811) which was reprinted in 1980 and which also contains the story ["Hyperpilosity"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48089) by [L. Sprague de Camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._Sprague_de_Camp).

Sturgeon's mad scientist explains the plan to his wife:

> "Obvious, isn't it? The source of woman's persistent and effective control over man, the thing that makes him subject to all her intolerances, whims, and bewildering coyness, is the simple fact of her perennial availability. She has no regular and predictable cycle of desire. The lower animals have. During the brief time that a female mouse, a marten, or a mare is approachable, every male of her species in the vicinity will know of it and seek her out; will, in effect, drop everything to answer a basic call. But unless and until that call occurs, the male is free to think of other things. With the human female, on the other hand, the call is mildly present at all times, and the male is never completely free to think of other things. It is natural for this drive to be strong. It is unnatural indeed for it to be constant.In this respect Freud was quite correct; nearly every neurosis has a sexual basis. We are a race of neurotics, and the great wonder is that we have retained any of the elements of sanity at all. I shall liberate humanity from this curse. I shall restore the natural alternations of drive and rest. I shall free men to think and women to take
> their rightful places as thinking individuals beside them, rather than be the forced-draft furnaces of sexual heat they have become."
>
> "Are you telling me," sajd Lucinda in a small, shocked voice, that you have found a way to—to neuterize women except for a few hours a month?"
>
> "I am and I have," said Dr. Lefferts.

Of course it goes wrong:

> "Jenny, do you feel any difference in yourself?"
>
> "Why, no. All die difference is in Bob. That's what I—"
>
> "Honey, there isn't any difference in you, nor in me, nor in any other woman. For the very first time in his scientific life, the great man made an error in his calculations."
>
> There was silence for a time, then the telephone uttered a soft, delighted, long-drawn-out “Oh-h-h-h-h ..."
>
> Lucinda said, "He's sure that in the long run it will have all the
> benefits he described—the longer life expectancy, the subduing of insecurities, the streamlining of our manners and customs."
>
> "You mean that all men from now on will . . "
>
> "I mean that for about twelve days in every two weeks, men can't do anything with us, which is restful. And for forty-eight hours they can't do anything without us, which is"—she laughed—"useful. It would seem that *homo sapiens* is still an atypical mammal."
>
> Jenny's voice was awed. "And I thought we were going to lose the battle of the sexes. Bob brings me little presents every single day, Lucinda!"
>
> "He'd better. Jenny, put down that phone and come over here. I want to hug you. And—" She glanced over at the hall closet, where hung the symbol of her triumph—"I want to show you my new fur coat."

Comment: I was pretty close given that I read this in the early 80s.